# Map 1 to 12 to set of decimals

Tags: matlab

I have a vector `m` which ranges from 1 to 12 randomly.

```
3    12    12     7    10     3     6    12    10    12
```

I have a conversion table

`1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12`

`0.6 0.7 1.8 0.9 0.5 1.6 0.9 1.5 1.8 0.8 0.9 0.5`

That means if `m(1)==3`, I want to change `m(1)` to be `1.8`.
if `m(2)==12`, I want to change `m(2)` to be `0.5`.

May I know what it the quickest way to do this conversion? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done with [indexing](https://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html)

```
conversion_table = [0.6 0.7 1.8 0.9 0.5 1.6 0.9 1.5 1.8 0.8 0.9 0.5];
m = [3 12 12  7 10  3  6 12 10 12];
m = conversion_table(m)
```